# Photo Editor with Cordova Suggestions

Tags: cordova, editor, ionic-framework, photo, aviary

Is there any available plugin to edit photos with a Ionic/Cordova app?
I was trying to use Aviary, but I am wondering if there are other options.

Comment: Aviary is the only option right now

Answer (score 0):

It seems like PhotoEditor from img.ly is going to be competitor for aviary since it is more responsive and more easy-to-customize. However after a lot of search I ended up with any plugin.That's one important disadvantage. :(